# ImmutableJS: get Todos array by Activity Id

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I can get Activity using temp.get('Activity');

**How can I get Todos array by Activity Id?**

```
Activity > id: 1 > Todos [All Objects]

var temp = Immutable.fromJS([
      {
        id: 1, userName: 'test', isActive: true,
        Activity: [
          {
            id: 1, text: 'This is Activity 1', isCompleted: false, addedOn: '', Todos: [
              { id: 1, text: 'Activity 1 Todo 1', isCompleted: false, progress: [1] },
              { id: 2, text: 'Activity 1 Todo 2', isCompleted: true,  progress: [2] },
              { id: 3, text: 'Activity 1 Todo 3', isCompleted: false, progress: [3] }
            ]
          }, {
            id: 2, text: 'This is Activity 2', isCompleted: false, addedOn: '', Todos: [
              { id: 1, text: 'Activity 2 Todo 1', isCompleted: true, progress: [4] },
              { id: 2, text: 'Activity 2 Todo 2', isCompleted: false, progress: [5] },
              { id: 3, text: 'Activity 2 Todo 3', isCompleted: false, progress: [6] }
            ]
          }
        ],
      }])
```

**Edit**

Here is more info

```
const result = temp.find(function(obj){return (obj.get('id') === 1 && obj.get('isActive'));});
console.log(result.getIn(['Activity', '0', 'Todo']));
```

with `['Activity', '0', 'Todo']` get what I want but problem is Activity is retrieved by index but **I want it by property id**.

Comment: Are you sure you can get the value of Activity using temp.get('Activity') ? That would be undefined since temp is a List. There is also a ',' missing after userName: 'test'

Comment: @QoP have removed extra properties from Array. I have proper working array and getting Activities fine. I need to get Todos of Selected Activity.

Comment: So temp is a Map or a List? You could use temp.get('Activity') if it was a map, but it's a List, https://jsfiddle.net/o04btr3j/201/

Comment: Edited my question and added more info at the bottom. temp is list.

Comment: Oh I get it now, I guess this is what you want, https://jsfiddle.net/o04btr3j/205/